# CloudBlockBlob downloadBlockList Sometimes throw Storage Exception (failed to authenticate)

Tags: java, azure

I am implementing a chunked upload solution for my service, which stores blobs in Azure. This is written in Clojure, using azure-sdk-for-java. I am able to upload and commit chunks as blocks in a block blob. Before I upload any block, however, some validation must be performed. This includes things such as checking how much the user has uploaded so far against the content-range they supply (we do not allow blocks to be re-uploaded).

To accomplish these checks, I am using CloudBlockBlob's method, downloadBlockList to get data about committed and uncommitted blocks as needed (and also to get the block list when it is time to commit). On some occasions, though, this fails, and I receive the following exception: "com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."

This is strange because I never get this failure if I call downloadBlockList after uploading a block, but I get it (on some occasions, but always the same occasions) if I call the method and don't upload. If I catch the exception and immediately call downloadBlockList again, it works fine.

I have used tcpdump to take a look at the headers that are being sent, as on some forums people have mentioned x-ms-date being set wrong, but this is not the case, and nothing looks incorrect. The response is 403, and complains about the MAC signature in the request being wrong.

Does anyone have any ideas why this would happen sometimes, but if I call the method again, immediately after, in an identical way, it works?

Answer (score 0):

I work on the Azure Storage SDKs. Could you provide the trace you mentioned. And if possible the account name / time this error occurred so I can look into this on our end. You can send privately to joegiard at Microsoft /.com.

We will update this thread for the stackoverflow community with the results of the investigations.

joe

Comment: Thanks Joe, I sent an email

Comment: Just to add something else I've discovered. If I use the rest API to examine one of my failed blobs I get some strange responses. At the point of failure there should be 2 uncommitted blocks and no committed blocks. If I use the query parameters ?comp=blocklist&timeout=90&blocklisttype=COMMITTED, I correctly get an XML response that shows there are no committed blocks, but if I use all or uncommitted as the blocklisttype, I get a 404 error saying the resource does not exist